# Finding coordinates in the ZXing library and outputting on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, qr-code, zxing

I'm using this [JS code scanner](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/) based on the [ZXing library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) and I would like to find the coordinates of the QR code found and then put a border around the found QR code on the `<canvas>` element. I cannot find the vars containing the coordinates of the QR code. I cannot find any good information on the net either, so I would appreciate any help.

**Note:** It would be helpful if you could tell me what vars have the coordinates saved; I'll be much closer to the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: This is a shot in the dark as I can't test it.*

In detector.js there is a `detect` method that returns the object "info". This object has the properties:

```
var topLeft = info.TopLeft;
var topRight = info.TopRight;
var bottomLeft = info.BottomLeft;
```

You can see these variables in action in the `processFinderPatternInfo` method.

Comment: Thanks, this brought me further! Managed to mark border on code on canvas. :)

Answer (score -2):

If you're using jQuery, you can find the position of any element using `$(element).position`

It should be easy enough to find the ID or Class the QR code belongs to and find the position of it.

http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to find the position of a element in a canvas (It's a bit more complicated)

Comment: @Florija Oh I understand what you mean now. My mistake.